# In Pandas, how do I drop rows based on date index not in date range?

Tags: python, pandas

I have some data in a dataframe with an date index:

```
              SP500_movement  SP500_movement_5days  SP500_movement_21days
Date                                                                   
2021-03-08             NaN                   NaN                    NaN
2021-03-09        0.013957                   NaN                    NaN
2021-03-10        0.005994                   NaN                    NaN
```

How do I drop all the rows that's not in the date range specified?  This is what I have tried.

```
        data = data.drop(data.loc[data.index < startDate])
        data = data.drop(data.loc[data.index > endDate])
```

The date range are in startDate, endDate, which are both in datetime format.

This is the error I get:

```
KeyError: "['SP500_movement' 'SP500_movement_5days' 'SP500_movement_21days'] not found in axis"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us do this

```
data = data.loc[(data.index >= startDate) & (data.index <= endDate)])
```

Or if you index is data time format

```
data = data.loc[startDate : endDate,:]
```

Comment: Second one worked for me, also, you got 255k reputation, you are one crazy man.

Comment: @BillSoftwareEngineer just spend some night and to help the community ~